# Preferred way to install multiple python versions on Ubuntu Jaunty

Tags: ubuntu, vim, python, ubuntu-9.04

Situation: **Jaunty** ships with **2.6**, which does not fit my needs because **many libraries are still failing**. I want to have a **system default 2.5**. Also, for testing purposes, I need **2.6, 2.5 and 2.4** installed.

**Current solution:**
I compiled 2.5 and 2.4 from source, and symlinked 2.5 to /usr/bin/python. I also edited some magic file that Ubuntu uses to specify Python version (don't remember now where it sits).

**Problems:**
First problem I'm having is that sometimes aptitude installs libraries for 2.6. In most cases, that's avoidable with suffixing -25.

But that's not always the solution, eg. Vim is compiled with 2.6, which does not have access to 2.5 libraries. **There is no way to install Vim with python 2.5**

Another problem I had recenty is that I installed **bypthon**. It was failing when using "curses" module, because it was from 2.6 library. I have no idea why/how this happens.

Anyone care to elaborate **how to do proper switching of default python in Jaunty**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to install 2.4, 2.5, 2.6 and/or 3.0 from the repositories using Synaptic Package Manager or `apt-get` or `aptitude` then use `update-alternatives` to set up a default. See my answer [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/64624/debian-python2-6-as-default/64637#64637) for information on using `update-alternatives` (the answer is even specific to Python).

Comment: which still lets "aptitude install python-package" do it's work for 2.6 even if I have 2.5 installed. But at least I'm pretty sure now that Ubuntu is Python unfriendly;)

Comment: Note that this breaks upgrading to 9.10!

Answer (score 4):

[**Installing multiple versions of Python on Ubuntu from Source**](http://achinghead.com/archive/83/installing-multiple-versions-python/)

Comment: This is first google hit and also just the way I have my current Python layout. Still, those two bugs are not avoidable with this solution.

Answer (score -1):

I know a number of people also use 'virtualenv' to create sub-environments with different versions and libraries.

Check it here: [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv)

Comment: In order to use virtualenv with different versions, you need binaries. I'm using virtualenv almost anywhere, just for pygtk development I need system python.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, haven't used it myself, stuck doing .NET all day :(